# Questions on using the upgrade assistant to convert app from Xamarin.Forms to MAUI

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui, .net-maui

Trying to use the upgrade assistant tool to upgrade a Xamarin.Forms 5 app to a .net Maui app.

1. Read in documentation there was [a MAUI extension](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.DotNet.UpgradeAssistant.Extensions.Maui#readme-body-tab) that could help with the conversion so ran the tool with the extensions option -  'extensions add Microsoft.DotNet.UpgradeAssistant.Extensions.Maui' and the output indicated that the extension was added successfully. However after starting the upgrade the first thing that pops up is 'Could not load extension from Microsoft.DotNet.UpgradeAssistant.Extensions.Maui'. Is this extension still needed? A usage example on how to properly install and use it would be great.
2. Ran the upgrade against the solution file which I thought would convert all projects in the solution. However it only converts the android project and the xamarin.forms project. Then have to run the tool a 2nd time against the iOS project. Is there a way to instruct the tool to simply convert all projects within the solution?
3. After the tool has completed the solution is still in the old Xamarin.Forms structure but was expecting it to be in the new MAUI folder structure. Is that something we have to do manually instead?
4. What is meant by 'SDK Style'? Hear that term thrown around a lot but clueless as to what it means. Is it another term for the new Maui folder structure?
5. Can't find any good examples on how to use the script. The one YouTube video found is a year old and script was executed from within VS and not from command-line. Are we suppose to run the tool from VS and not command-line? Would be nice to see a 80/20 demo done from the command-line i.e. by 80/20 demo I mean "most of you just want to convert all projects in the solution; let's walk thru an example of that...". Really just want to run the script in non-interactive mode and have it convert all projects.

After reading thru [the documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Migrating-from-Xamarin.Forms-(Preview)) and assuming the upgrade tool will not create the expected Maui folder structure, is it better to just create a new MAUI project and copy everything over? Was thinking to have 2 branches; on one branch run the upgrade script against it and 2nd branch will be a new MAUI project. Then copy over the upgraded class files and make in place changes as necessary. Any feedback on this approach would be appreciated.

Comment: *"is it better to just create a new MAUI project and copy everything over?"* Given the limitations you describe, that is what I would do. Caveat: I have not tested this tool; glad to hear it exists.